# Xamarin forms Geocoder GetPositionsForAddressAsync intermittent android results

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, geolocation, xamarin.forms

I have a weird issue with the geocoder class inside Xamarin forms.  Especially getpositionsforaddressaysnc.  iOS always returns a result but android results are intermittent.  When I send the address "2810 Birch street denver 80207" I will get a result.  If I type in "7001 tower rd denver 80249" I don't get a result.  Its a valid address.  You can type it into google maps.  I've tried various addresses and it seems very intermittent.  The code is..

```
var approximateLocations = await   geoCoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(address);
                if (approximateLocations.Any())
                {
                    success = true;
                }
```

I know my google api key is correct cause I can get results sometimes.  I've search other posts and nothing is helping.  I've got all the right android manifest elements required by Xamarin forms maps documentation.

I'm currently running Xamarin forms version 2.3.4.247.
Xamarin forms maps version 2.3.4.247
Xamarin google play services maps version 42.1021.1

Also I tried creating a fresh Xamarin forms project with the Xamarin packages stated above and I get the same android intermittent issues.

Please Help! :-)

Comment: Same issue here with **GetAddressesForPositionAsync** & **GetPositionsForAddressAsync** but the second thrown grpc failed error in android

Answer (score 2):

There is an open bug to track this issue.

[Bugzilla(39870)](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39870)

I think it isn´t resolved yet.